# Why when exporting package i'm getting message nothing to import?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What i want is to copy all the UI including all sub Objects and all dependencies to another project.

The problem is that after this message after few seconds he give me a new window to export the whole project the whole hierarchy.

And i want to export only the UI i also tried to mark first only the objects under UI. But same message.

To export i'm doing: Assets > Export Package...

[image: Export Message]

Comment: I tried now first to create a prefab out of the UI and then dragged the UI to the new prefab and then tried to make on the prefab right mouse click and Export Package... but same message and then he give me a window with many items to export not what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything in your Assets / Project selected. The message should probably read "nothing to **export**," but as the only thing you have selected is an object in your scene, which is not an asset, it cannot be exported so the message isn't actually in error, its just confusing.

As you discovered, you had to turn it into a prefab first. Alternatively, you could have exported the scene itself (which *does* exist in the Assets directory, provided it has been saved).